# Git refs/stash not empty but running git stash list shows nothing

Tags: git

On a Git repository, I can run the following:

```
$ git stash list
$ cat .git/refs/stash
22bfcca84458f21e63d37160a03f0cd5355517f2
```

So the `stash list` command shows an empty stash, but there is a stash reference. I'm trying to understand what is going on here. First of all, is this even a valid state? I presume the answer is yes, and that there is some cleanup that needs to run. But when I've done the following I get the show error:

```
$ git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (37/37), done.
$ git gc
fatal: error ummapping packed-refs file .git/packed-refs: Invalid argument
error: failed to run pack-refs
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Something *is* wrong (you should not get that error) but it's not clear what, at this point. If you're on Linux you could use `strace` to see the specific failing system call and do further digging from there.

Comment: Had the same problem when trying to run `git remote prune`, your solutions helped as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I can't say I completely understand what happened, but I think everything is back to normal. I noticed that `.git/packed-refs` was an empty file, so on a backup of my repo, I did the following:

```
$ rm .git/packed-refs
$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (37/37), done.
$ git gc
Counting objects: 166, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (154/154), done.
Writing objects: 100% (166/166), done.
Total 166 (delta 73), reused 34 (delta 9)
$ git stash list
$ cat .git/refs/stash
cat: .git/refs/stash: No such file or directory
```

I'm answering here on the off chance it helps someone else. I don't completely understand what went on here. Comments welcome.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Wound up being a huge help.